# How to extend a same name method and get called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, overriding

I like to rewrite a method in a class, so I extend the method with same name and parameter, but it never get called.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

.... An extension method with the same name and signature as an interface or class method will never be called. ....

Ok, I have to accept this.

My question is:
for a unsealed class (and even I have source code), if I like to rewrite a method **OUTSide** of the class ( in a different project but same solution), how?

**[EDIT]**

Here is the way suggested, use virtual/override, no error on runtime, no error on compile, just never get called too :(, please take a look

In Project A:

```
public class CachePlan : ICachePlan
{
    public virtual CacheSettings GetPlan(ControllerContext filterContext)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In Project B:

```
public class CachePlanExtension: CachePlan
{
    public override CacheSettings GetPlan(ControllerContext filterContext)
    {
        CacheSettings ca = new CacheSettings();
        ca.IsCachingEnabled = true;
        ca.Duration = 100;
        return ca;
    }
}
```

**But never get called, CashPlan.GetPlan still return null. Anyidea?**

Comment: Please say what you're trying to accomplish, and not how you're trying to accomplish it.

Comment: Technically you just about always have the code to a .NET library. It might be obfuscated, but likely its just IL, not pre-jitted code.

Comment: Not answer to your question, but we still have ability to call extension method in this situation, we just need to call it like non-extension static helper method. example: `static class SomeExtensions { public static void DoSomething(this ISomething something) { ... } }` instead of using `s.DoSomething();`, call `SomeExtensions.DoSomething(s);`

Comment: What I like to have is a method like "OnResultExecuting" in "ActionFilterAttribute" that I can rewrite it.

Comment: method named OnResultExecuting (because it named with prefix [On]) I think should be virtual, so you could override it, just as competent_tech suggested. So, check original method, does it have `virtual` modifier?

Comment: What is `ICachePlan`? It's not part of MVC.

Comment: Ohh, some of my interface, I am not paste here because its not related to the question. I tried remove the interface and just pure class, still same problem

Comment: can you show the code that calls `GetPlan(...)` ?

Comment: Do you instantiate `CachePlanExtension` instead of `CachePlan`?

Comment: Hi @Alexander, that works but not my goal, I want to change the original class, not make a new class.

Comment: Hm... if so, I can't understand what you trying to do, could you provide a code which calls GetPlan() method, and I'll try to suggest you how to resolve your problem.

Comment: Mono.Cecil could help you to rewrite any code in any compiled assembly, but this is bad idea, because: 1) It will take much time, 2) Its hard to maintain, 3) It seems like a hack solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension method like this (note the this-keyword in the GetPlan()-parameter list):

```
public class CachePlanExtension //does not have to be static
{
    public static CacheSettings GetPlan(this CachePlan cachePlan, ControllerContext filterContext) //has to be static!
    {
        //the cachePlan-Parameter will later contain the CachePlan-object, on which you call this method. Example:
        var name = cachePlan.Name;


        CacheSettings ca = new CacheSettings();
        ca.IsCachingEnabled = true;
        ca.Duration = 100;
        return ca;
    }
}
```

Whenever you can "see" the extension class (that means it must be public or internal, and you have to includ the namespace of the extension class) you can call the method like this:

```
new CachePlan().GetPlan(filterContext);
```

Comment: My code was **override** for GetPlan, so I change it to static, not working, complile warning: "To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword." So I change to "static override", compile error "A static member 'CachePlanExtension.GetPlan(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext)' cannot be marked as override, virtual, or abstract." So I have to remove "static", then I back where I started. Any idea?

Comment: "you have to includ the namespace of the extension class" ok I noticed this. But thats not my goal, I want to do totally out-of-the-class thing to change the method in-the-class.

Comment: with extension methods you can NOT change classes, but only extend them. For example: you can not change the Add() method of the List<string> class, but you could add a "AddCustom()"-method, which could perform some calculations and then call the List<string>.Add()-method.

Comment: Another example: the int-struct offers (like all objects) a ToString()-method. This method only returns the negative-sign, but not the positive-sign (like "-3", but if its positive it would be "3").
You could create an extension method ToStringSigned() or something similar and then call it like `int i=3; i.ToStringSigned();` for EVERY int value. But you cannot change the original ToString() method.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "reach into" an existing class and change the meaning of its methods. That would be a major security hole.

Comment: Thanks. But why at MVC, you can rewrite OnResultExecuting for ActionFilterAttribute?

Comment: That's not a rewrite, it's an override of a virtual method from a base class.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put; "not possible". As explained on the page...

> You can use extension methods to extend a class or interface, but not
>   to override them. An extension method with the same name and signature
>   as an interface or class method will never be called. At compile time,
>   extension methods always have lower priority than instance methods
>   defined in the type itself. In other words, if a type has a method
>   named Process(int i), and you have an extension method with the same
>   signature, the compiler will always bind to the instance method. When
>   the compiler encounters a method invocation, it first looks for a
>   match in the type's instance methods. If no match is found, it will
>   search for any extension methods that are defined for the type, and
>   bind to the first extension method that it finds.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code why not simply delete the implementation of the method from the original class and provide an extension method in a separate project

Comment: Because my 3 projects which depends on this 1 projects have different implement for the same method.

Comment: In fact, I tried this method. Because I need to call the method in original class, if I delete the implementation, I cannot compile the class. If I use GetMethod and invoke, problem is cannot find the extended method, even I tried the method by linq I found on Google :(

Comment: |The other option is to remove the class member method and provide two extension methods with the same signature in two different namespaces. One project can use one and the other can use the other.

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods are just syntatic sugar which gets compiled into static method calls. So you could just write a static method which accomplishes the same thing, you just wouldn't be able to call it exactly how you like. If the method is virtual you could override it in a derived class. Just make sure you always instantiate your own type. You could also use the `new` keyword, but a simple cast and your code won't be used. Best would be to create a simple wrapper class for yourself. That class would have an instance of the class in question, and figure out the right calls. This is very common when creating special collections, since a lot of the .NET collection types don't lend themselves very well to inheritance. But worst of all, you could use [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/).

**Edit**

Create your own class that inherits from the `ActionFilterAttribute` and use that to create your own custom filters.

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override virtual void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

To override that in the built in attributes would not be recommended, but you can hook into that method in a variety of other ways. But if you really want to do it, MVC is open source...

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method in an inherited class.

Comment: wouldn't shadowing in a subclass be overriding?

Comment: No: shadowing is used when the method is not declared as virtual.

Comment: Can the downvote please explain? The OP asked: how to rewrite the method. Both of my suggestions are perfectly valid and, in fact, the only options available.

Comment: Ah I see, was thinking about it from a Java polymorphism viewpoint. My bad.

Comment: @competent_tech in fact they're not. There are tricks which allow you to do it. [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) for example. Note, I didn't vote you down.

Comment: -1: he said to rewrite it and have it called. A shadowed method will not be called on a reference to the base class.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: Well, moles is definitely something new learned for me today. Thank you for pointing that out, I had absolutely no idea that existed.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: ok, I have updated my answer to just reference overrides, which is a valid solution.

Comment: +1 It seems like overriding is exactly what is in order here.